# Jquery get "this" from an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fetch a unique value from an element using jquery, this value is supposed to appear when I scroll to a certain place on the screen. When the element  is onscreen, the postId 15 is supposed to reach the jquery code.

This is my code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($("p.viewedPost").is(':onScreen')) {
        var postId = $(this).attr("postId");
        console.log("Element appeared on Screen " + postId);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Element not on Screen");
        //do all your stuffs here when element is not visible.
    }
});
```

The problem is that I have multiple postId's, so I can't use `$("p.viewedPost").attr("postId");`

It needs to be `$(this).attr("postId");`

But when I use "this", the postId appears to be undefined. So how can I get the `$("p.viewedPost").is(':onScreen')` to have a `this` ?

Thanks.

Comment: The if statement doesn't have it's own `this`. your logic is flawed.

Comment: Consider `$("p.viewedPost").each( ... )`

Comment: I understand that, but is there someway to fetch it to make its own "this"? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: `this` in this context is `document`. try `$("p.viewedPost:onScreen").attr('postId')`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev What if `$("p.viewedPost:onScreen")` returns multiple elements?

Comment: Thank you, ```$("p.viewedPost:onScreen").attr('postId')``` did the job!

Comment: @PVPSquad Not only is that shorthand for trincot's answer below (which you said won't work), without an `each` it will only work for the first element in the selection. If you have multiple `p.viewedPost` on screen at the same time, you'll only retrieve the `postId` of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `.filter()` and `.each()`:

```
$("p.viewedPost").filter(':onScreen').each(function () {
    var postId = $(this).attr("postId");
    console.log("Element appeared on Screen " + postId);
});
```

If your plugin's `:onScreen` selector does not work with `.filter`, then you can put the test inside the `each` callback:

```
$("p.viewedPost").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':onScreen')) return; // skip
    var postId = $(this).attr("postId");
    console.log("Element appeared on Screen " + postId);
});
```

Comment: This wont work since :onScreen doesn't support "filter".

Comment: It's a custom selector - how does it support `.is()` but not `.filter()`? If that really is the case it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: See addition to answer.